# pyspark read 1st n files into df

Tags: python, apache-spark

i'm trying out databricks platform, and i'm interested to load the first 6 files into the dataframe.

the data is stored in `dbfs:/mystore` and it is in the form of text/csv files.

```
part-00000
part-00001
part-00002
part-00003
part-00004
part-00005
part-00006
part-00007
part-00008
part-00009
part-00010
```

What I have done is create a spark session:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("tester").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`

and `df = spark.read.csv("dbfs:/mystore/*", header='true', inferSchema='true')`

But this reads everything into the dataframe. How do I only read the first 5 files `00000 - 00004` into the dataframe? - each file is very large, so I only want to play with the 1st 5 files only.

Also, as the headers are in `part-00000`, will I still be able to use `header="true"` for the `read.csv`? Because if i'm not mistaken, spark distributes the load when creating the dataframe, so the order won't be kept.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a quick and dirty solution to this.

basically use python to generate a list of qualified file locations, then just load that list into `spark.read.csv(list_of_file_locations)` then it works.